# Maclaurin series accuracy

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> Find an $n_1$ such that the $n_1$th-order Taylor polynomial for $\sin(x)$ about $x=0$ gives an approximation of $\sin(x)$ with an error of less than $5\cdot 10^{-10}$, for all $x$ between $0$ and $\dfrac{1}{2}\pi$. Your $n_1$ doesn't have to be the smallest possible $n_1$, but show it satisfies the requirements, without using a calculator. You can use $ 2< \pi < 4$.

So I know the following things. The maclaurin series for $\sin(x)$.

$$ \sin(x) = x - \dfrac{x^3}{3!} + \dfrac{x^5}{5!} - ... $$

And the error in the approximation:

$$ E_n(x) = \dfrac{f^{(n+1)}(s)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}$$ where $s$ is some number between $a$ and $x$. I'm not sure, but I believe we have $a=0$.

How do I tackle this problem? Should you set the error equal to $5\cdot10^{-10}$ and solve for $n$? Can we just choose $\pi = 3$ or $\pi = 3.5$ or whatever (I don't really understand what is meant by that)? What should we fill in for $s$ and $x$, and how can we show it satisfies the requirement for all possible $x$ in $[0, \dfrac{1}{2} \pi]$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$\displaystyle|E_n(x)|=\frac{|f^{n+1}(s)|}{(n+1)!}|(x-a)^{n+1}|$ where $|f^{n+1}(s)|\le1$ since
$f^{n+1}(s)=\pm\sin s$ or $f^{n+1}(s)=\pm\cos s$, so

$\displaystyle|E_n(x)|\le\frac{|x-0|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\le\frac{(\frac{\pi}{2})^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\le\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ since $\pi<4$.

Comment: So basically if we solve $5*10^{-10} \leq  \dfrac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$  for $n$ we get an answer?

Comment: You want to solve the reverse inequality, since you want $|E_n|\le5(10^{-10})$.

Comment: Thanks. I assume this means that if we replace sine by cosine in the question, we'd get the same answer?

Comment: Using this method, that is correct.  (This doesn't mean that the smallest value of $n_1$ will be the same for sine and cosine, though.)